# Objective-C dynamic properties at runtime?

Tags: objective-c

Is it possible to create an Objective-C class that can have an arbitrary number of dynamic properties at runtime?

I want to be able to call `mySpecialClass.anyProperty` and intercept this inside my class to be able to provide my own custom implementation that can then return an `NSString` (for instance) at runtime with raising an exception. Obviously this all has to compile.

Ideal would be if I could refer to my properties using something similar to the new literal syntax, e.g. `mySpecialClass["anyProperty"]`.

I guess in a way I want to create something like a dynamic NSDictionary with no CFDictionary backing store, that executes 2 custom methods on property getting and setting respectively, with the property name passed in to these accessor methods so they can decide what to do.

Comment: (There are three basic mechanisms: 1) actually add methods to the class, 2) intercept the "unrecognized message" error and supply an implementation, 3) for properties there is a specific way to intercept setters and getters.  But I don't have any of the details at hand.)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

There are at least two ways to do this.

## Subscripting

Use `objectForKeyedSubscript:` and `setObject:forKeyedSubscript:`

```
 @property (nonatomic,strong) NSMutableDictionary *properties;

 - (id)objectForKeyedSubscript:(id)key {
      return [[self properties] valueForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",key]];
 }

 - (void)setObject:(id)object forKeyedSubscript:(id <NSCopying>)key {
      [[self properties] setValue:object forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",key]];
 }

 Person *p = [Person new];
 p[@"name"] = @"Jon";
 NSLog(@"%@",p[@"name"]);
```

## resolveInstanceMethod:

This is the objc_sendMsg executed by the runtime for all methods:

[image: objc_sendMsg]

If you look at the bottom, you have the opportunity to `resolveInstanceMethod:`, which lets you redirect the method call to one of your choosing. To answer your question, you need to write a generic getter and setter that looks-up a value on a dictionary ivar:

```
// generic getter
static id propertyIMP(id self, SEL _cmd) {
    return [[self properties] valueForKey:NSStringFromSelector(_cmd)];
}


// generic setter
static void setPropertyIMP(id self, SEL _cmd, id aValue) {

    id value = [aValue copy];
    NSMutableString *key = [NSStringFromSelector(_cmd) mutableCopy];

    // delete "set" and ":" and lowercase first letter
    [key deleteCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(0, 3)];
    [key deleteCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange([key length] - 1, 1)];
    NSString *firstChar = [key substringToIndex:1];
    [key replaceCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(0, 1) withString:[firstChar lowercaseString]];

    [[self properties] setValue:value forKey:key];
}
```

And then implement `resolveInstanceMethod:` to add the requested method to the class.

```
+ (BOOL)resolveInstanceMethod:(SEL)aSEL {
    if ([NSStringFromSelector(aSEL) hasPrefix:@"set"]) {
        class_addMethod([self class], aSEL, (IMP)setPropertyIMP, "v@:@");
    } else {
        class_addMethod([self class], aSEL,(IMP)propertyIMP, "@@:");
    }
    return YES;
}
```

You could also do it returning a NSMethodSignature for the method, which is then wrapped in a NSInvocation and passed to `forwardInvocation:`, but adding the method is faster.

[Here is a gist](https://gist.github.com/4175830) that runs in CodeRunner. It doesn't handle `myClass["anyProperty"]` calls.

Comment: The code is from "iOS 5 Programming Pushing the Limits" by Rob Napier and Mugunth Kumar. Chapter 20: Deep Objective-C explains how to implement @dynamic properties. The book has a few advanced techniques like that one. I made the graphic with Omnigraffle with info from the book and several places.

Comment: +1… [as noted by Mike Ash](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2010-11-6-creating-classes-at-runtime-in-objective-c.html), it's often better to look up the type encodings rather than hard code them.

Comment: Holy crap, I've been tweaking an implementation of a dynamic "property bucket" where my code was 90% of this and you finished it off. @Jano, one big question, what do you do if the property is not an object? In other words, "id aValue" will give you an EXC_BAD_ACCESS?

Answer (score 2):

You're asking different things. If you want to be able to use the bracket syntax `mySpecialClass[@"anyProperty"]` on instances of your class, it is very easy. Just implement the methods:

```
 - (id)objectForKeyedSubscript:(id)key
 {
      return ###something based on the key argument###
 }

 - (void)setObject:(id)object forKeyedSubscript:(id <NSCopying>)key
 {
      ###set something with object based on key####
 }
```

It will be called everytime you use the bracket syntax in your source code.

Otherwise if you want to create properties at runtime, there are different ways to proceed, take a look at `NSObject`'s `forwardInvocation:` method, or look at the [Objective-C Runtime Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html) for functions to dynamically alter a class...

Comment: This isn't correct, those methods are [only defined on NSDictionary](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=objectForKeyedSubscript&t=osx&ia=web) and in some other frameworks, you can't add subscripts to a arbitrary NSObject just by defining them.

Comment: Of course you can, that is why these two methods exist. Have you even tried to implement them?

Answer (score 1):

Guillaume is right. `forwardInvocation:` is the way to go. This answer gives some more details: [method_missing-like functionality in objective-c (i.e. dynamic delegation at run time)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4630797/method-missing-like-functionality-in-objective-c-i-e-dynamic-delegation-at-run)

This has even more details: [Equivalent of Ruby method_missing in Objective C / iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9800293/equivalent-of-ruby-method-missing-in-objective-c-ios)

And these are some other lesser known Obj-C features that might help you: [Hidden features of Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211616/hidden-features-of-objective-c)

Enjoy!