# Core Data cloud sync

Tags: ios, core-data, synchronization, parse-platform

I am working on Core Data app which needs to sync data to various platforms including the web. Initially I started integrating [Stackmob](http://stackmob.com) which seemed a fine candidate to handle this task. Now that Stackmob is apparently shutting [down](https://blog.stackmob.com/2014/02/stackmob-announcement/) I'm looking for another BaaS framework/service as a replacement. Everyone is suggesting to use [Parse.com](http://parse.com) but parse is an 'always online' service which does not support offline sync. The users of my app need to be able to use the app offline, and sync the cached data as soon as the device has internet connection.

Building my own syncing backend is not an option at this moment since I'm a small developer who has not the time nor the resources to do this. What are my options, are there any similar services which support offline sync for Core Data ?

note: I can't use iCloud since I want to sync to the web.

update:
I stumbled upon [Simperium](http://simperium.com/) which seems to do offline Core Data syncing. Anyone having any experience with this service ?

Comment: Parse.com offers the ability to use a local cache for all your data, and you can specify that you want to hit the network before cache. This means that if network is down, your app will still work against the cache.

Comment: Another solution is, as I have done in one of my apps, to use Core Data in conjunction with Parse. One part of my app must always be accessible, so those data are stored in Core Data AND parse.com. When the app loads, it checks for updated remote data, and syncs if it finds any.

Comment: Doing the syncing manually is indeed an option but IMO only feasible if your CoreData schema is kept very simple. My schema is quite complex with lot's of relations and multiple tables. Building a syncing engine which does resolve conflicts and merging will require a big effort and take a long time.

Comment: Agreed. In that case, I should think the cache feature should be what you need. http://blog.parse.com/2011/09/30/easy-caching-with-parse/

Comment: Thanks for the link. But Parse's caching does not seem to do syncing as well.

Comment: I am looking into parse.com myself.  Is there a reason that parse.com's saveEventually won't work here?  What do you mean it doesn't sync very well? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13645666/objective-c-dynamic-methods-at-runtime.

Comment: I think it's generally a good idea not to couple the app too tightly with Parse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest the [Dropbox Datastore API](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/datastore). You can use the [ParcelKit](https://github.com/overcommitted/ParcelKit) wrapper which allows you to use Core Data. This gives you everything you need: offline use, Core Data, and a Javascript API for your web component.

There is also [Wasabi Sync](http://wasabisync.com), which is Core Data-native, and has a REST API for web use.

If you can drop the requirement for web, there are solutions like [Ensembles](https://github.com/drewmccormack/ensembles) and [TICDS](https://github.com/nothirst/TICoreDataSync), which work with multiple backends (e.g. iCloud, Dropbox). (Disclosure: I develop Ensembles)

Comment: Dropbox Datastore seemed at first a fine candidate but apparently it does not support multi-user collaboration which is a deal-breaker for my app.

Comment: I should add that there is nothing stopping multiple users sharing a store with Ensembles. It is backend agnostic, and is just a question of adopting a multi-user backend. That said, you still have the issue of it not working with the web.

Answer (score 1):

There is an open source package called FTASync that syncs Parse with CoreData. I looked at using it, but it was too simplistic for my app. Although I am a lone developer like you I took on the task of modifying FTASync into what I need. I have it pretty much finished now and it is very different from  FTASync. If FTASync is not sufficient for you, contact me privately and perhaps we can work something out.

-Bob

Comment: I have no idea how to contact you. But I know about FTASync and did some small tests with it. Unfortunately the library seemed quite immature, syncing did not work as expected and crashed frequently especially when using data relations.

Comment: Sorry, I assumed there was a "Private Message" capability somewhere on SO, but I can't find one. Try bob in the domain theralynx dot com.